# Did the disciples believe that Jesus was omniscient?

Tags: john, christology, attributes-of-god, knowledge

John 16:29-30 (ESV):

> 29 His disciples said, “Ah, now you are speaking plainly and not using figurative speech! 30 Now we know that **you know all things** and do not need anyone to question you; this is why we believe that you came from God.”

John 21:17 (ESV):

> 17 He said to him the third time, “Simon, son of John, do you love me?” Peter was grieved because he said to him the third time, “Do you love me?” and he said to him, “**Lord, you know everything**; you know that I love you.” Jesus said to him, “Feed my sheep.

Did the disciples believe that Jesus was omniscient?

---

Related question: [Did Jesus exercise omniscience or a spiritual gift in Matthew 9:4?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/57067/did-jesus-exercise-omniscience-or-a-spiritual-gift-in-matthew-94)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the OP's list, we might also add another, also from the Gospel of John 2:24, 25 -

> But Jesus did not entrust Himself to them, for He knew them all. He
> did not need any testimony about man, for He knew what was in a man.

According to John 14:12 -

> Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever believes in Me will also do the
> works that I am doing. He will do even greater things than these,
> because I am going to the Father.

We see evidence of this in some of the actions of the apostles such as:

- Acts 27:10 - saying to them, "Men, I understand that the voyage is about to be filled with disaster and much loss, not only of the cargo and of the ship, but also of our lives."
- Acts 8:23 - For I see that you are in the gall of bitterness and in the bondage of unrighteousness.”

That is, the apostles and NT prophets also had access, via the Holy Spirit, into men's hearts.  They opened great truths of the Bible (John 16:13), they predicted the future (as above) and they revealed the secrets of men's hearts.

Again, while I believe in the full, innate omniscience of Jesus, this was one of His divine powers he did not exercise in while incarnate, to show us how to live in complete dependence on God.  See John 14:12, Heb 4:14-16, etc.